# Crontab timing working not as expected

Tags: cron, cronexpression

I have a backup script syncing some files every 3rd day.

```
# m    h   dom  mon  dow
  0    5   */3    *    *     backup      /home/backup/scripts/system_backup.sh
```

Today I was checking the backup and there was none.

I expected, because today is the 27th, `27 / 3` is an even number, it would execute.

The timestamps of the other backups contain the days `19`, `22`, `25`

Shouldn't it execute like on the days `18`, `21`, `24`, `27` ?

A timestamp of the server right now is `Fri Jun 27 08:52:00 UTC 2014`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page for `crontab(5)`:

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with ``/'' specifies skips of the number's value through the range.

Basically, what this means is that values are used at 0-based indexes that are divisible by `<number>`.

For dom, `*` is the same as `1-31`. So `*/3` is `1-31/3`. Which means it'll start at 1 (index 0) then add 3 to get to the next one (4, at index 3) and so on.

If you want the cron to run on days that are divisible by three, you can use `3-31/3` instead.

Comment: So left side is range and right side are the steps. When I say every second day now, it sounds logical to me (1, 3, 5 - no multiplies of 2). Thanks!